# Как расшифровать \\u042d\\u0441\\u043a\\u0438\\u043c в кириллицу в c#

Tags: c#

Я из строки JSON вытаскиваю вот такой текст: `\u042d\u0441\u043a\u0438\u043c\u043e \u041c\u0410\u0413\u041d\u0410\u0422 \u0428\u043e\u043a\u043e\u043b\u0430\u0434\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0442\u0440\u044e\u0444\u0435\u043b\u044c, 72\u0433`

И когда пресваеваю его  переменной, он становится таким :`\\u042d\\u0441\\u043a\\u0438\\u043c\\u043e \\u041c\\u0410\\u0413\\u041d\\u0410\\u0422 \\u0428\\u043e\\u043a\\u043e\\u043b\\u0430\\u0434\\u043d\\u044b\\u0439 \\u0442\\u0440\\u044e\\u0444\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c, 72\\u0433`

Как мне убрать лишние слеши? Из за них слеш перестаёт быть спецсимволом и компилятор не может расшифровать эти цифро-букво-сочетания в буквы кириллицы. Пробовал разными способами что-то сделать, но в итоге в консоль выводится либо это `\u042d\u0441\u043a\u0438\u043c\u043e \u041c\u0410\u0413\u041d\u0410\u0422 \u0428\u043e\u043a\u043e\u043b\u0430\u0434\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0442\u0440\u044e\u0444\u0435\u043b\u044c, 72\u0433`. А если пытаюсь убрать слеши с помощью `Remove(@"\","")` , то просто выводятся буквы и цифры без слеша.

Comment: а почему не использовать обычный парсер json, который сам сконвертирует эти коды в буквы?

Comment: [Как сериализировать и десериализировать JSON в .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to). Стандартный сериализатор вам всё что нужно достанет.

Comment: "И когда пресваеваю его переменной, он становится таким :\\u042d\\u0441\\..." - бэкслэши здесь не добавляются, просто так отображается значение переменной. На самом деле там бэкслэш один, как и в исходном JSON.

Comment: Если очень хочется самому преобразовать, то используйте "String.Concat(Array.ConvertAll<string,char>(a.Split(new string[]{ "\\u" },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries),(f)=>{var b=Convert.FromHexString(f); return (char)((b[0]<<8)+b[1]);}))", где "a" - это входная строка.

Comment: @rotabor зачем? Если уж идти на изврат, то есть `Regex.Unescape` готовый. Попробуйте.

Comment: @aepot Попробовал, работает. :-) Вчера погуглил, поискал в String, Char, Convert - не нашёл, а в голове крутилось, что где-то есть.